# How to add URL comment to word document using c#?

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, comments, office-interop

This is my code. I can put comment but I want to put URL in the comment.
How can I do this?

```
  using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
  using Microsoft.Office.Core;

  private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Open a doc file.
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application application = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document document = application.Documents.Open(@"e:\temp3.docx");
        object comment = "www.google.com" + Environment.NewLine;
        object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Comment var = document.Comments.Add(document.Words[1], comment);
        try {
            document.Hyperlinks.Add(var.Range,ref missing,ref missing,ref missing,ref missing,ref missing);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString()); }
        document.Close();
        application.Quit();
    }
```

**But result is this**

[image: my objective]

[And bad parameter exception in Hyperlink.add](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CEZGz.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Open a doc file.
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application application = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document document = application.Documents.Open(@"e:\temp3.docx");
        object comment = "www.google.com" + Environment.NewLine;
        object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Comment var = document.Comments.Add(document.Words[1], comment);
        try {
            document.Hyperlinks.Add(var.Range,ref comment,ref missing,ref missing,ref missing,ref missing);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString()); }
        document.Close();
        application.Quit();
    }
```

In HyperLinks.Add instead of ref comment i had put ref missing .

Answer (score 0):

```
// Insert a hyperlink to the Web page.
object oAddress = "http://www.microsoft.com";
object oRange = wrdSelection.Range;
document.Hyperlinks.Add(oRange, ref oAddress, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
```

Comment: I want put URL in my comment but your solution is for inserting URL in document text. check this  http://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVqRN.png

Comment: @Isuru Your link is not relevant as that uses the Open XML SDK, not the Word object model. Your overall approach is correct, however. The OP just has to pass the correct RANGE to the method.

Comment: @Pouriagolshanrad. You have all the information you need, you just have to combine it. The Comments.Add method returns a Comments object, so assign a variable to it. The Comment Object has a Range property, which you then pass to Hyperlinks.Add that Isuru has given you, in place of oRange.